# Why do MLB games start at incremental times; e.g. 7:05, 6:10, etc?

Tags: mlb, media

Why don't they simply start at the top or bottom of the hour; e.g. 7:00, 6:00, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to support telecasts by establishing a pre-game (which teams are playing, presenting any relevant storylines for the teams, etc) and providing opportunities for advertising (ie, commercials).

In media terms, it's a lead-in to the actual start of a game, rather than an abrupt introduction to the first pitch of the game.